# SPP Bluetooth profile compatibility with phone

Tags: microcontroller

I'm building a project that uses a cell phone to control a microcontroller via Bluetooth.

I've decided to use the HC-05 Bluetooth module.

HC-05 Manual: http://www.exp-tech.de/service/datasheet/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products.pdf

And the phone I'm using is the Nokia C3-00 (series 40).

http://developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/C3-00/

The HC-05 module uses the SPP Bluetooth profile while my phone only supports DUN, FTP, GAP, GOEP, HFP, HSP, OPP, PAN, SAP, SDAP profiles. But to my knowledge the phone API utilizes RFCOMM.

Question is, can I use this Bluetooth module with my phone?

Thanks in advance and my apologies if my question is too trivial as I'm quite new to Bluetooth.

-Shaun